# What is a word for "the desire to be considered a victim"?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

I'm wondering about this in relation to the notion of a "culture of victimization", when people want to garner sympathy and/or discharge their guilt by being considered victims.

The phrase "culture of victimization" refers to the situation of many people having that desire and not to the desire itself. "Masochism" is close I suppose, but somehow not quite right.

Comment: Reminds me of the book, "I'm OK; you're a pain in the neck."

Answer (score 4):

The expression *self pity* is perhaps more accurate than "masochism".

Masochism has certain additional connotations, quite separate from the desire to garner sympathy or discharge perceived guilt.

Answer (score 3):

Some friends have suggested "martyr complex" and "victim complex". Those are pretty good, let's see if any other suggestions come up.

Comment: You'll presumably be aware that *martyr* and *victim* have significantly different meanings. "Martyr complex" is quite a well-established term in psychology, but in common speech they're almost interchangeable, and I think you may actually be more likely to hear "victim complex" in general conversation.

Answer (score 2):

While technically the act rather than the desire, "[victim playing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victim_playing)" seems to be a good fit.

Comment: so tempted to accept this answer because this is the best fit for the way I want to use the term, but technically this isn't the desire