# Word for someone who pities, insults or complaints about their situation or life just to make the other person flatter them

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

I want to know a ***word*** or a ***phrase*** that would describe a person who **"intentionally"** (*because some people hate themselves even when they don't want to, or some people are insecure - making some generalizations, forgive me if I miss out something.*) insults themselves to make others try to make them feel better by complimenting them. Here is an example of a conversation :

A: Hello B, how is it going?

B: Nice. I just wish my purple dress didn't make me look even uglier.

A: That isn't the case babe, I think you are amazing. You are really soo beautiful.

B: NO I am HIDEOUS, and I know it, don't lie to me.

A: No, I promise. I won't lie you're my BFF. You Rock girl.

Comment: I found one word on google search: shuckster. But that isn't well known not even as a slang. I would really prefer a word that is in the dictionary if possible.

Comment: If 'Word for person who looks for flattery' is deemed not to be a duplicate, then answers such as 'fishing for compliments' must be deemed too hypernymic also. Perhaps [word for someone intentionally punishing self to get reactions ... pity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317439/word-for-someone-intentionally-punishing-self-to-get-reactions-pity/317442#317442) is not quite close enough either. ('Martyr' is offered here.) Or [person who brags about difficulties](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287760/describe-a-person-who-brags-about-difficulties/287769#287769).

Comment: Certainly [What is a word for the desire to be considered a victim?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61021/what-is-a-word-for-the-desire-to-be-considered-a-victim/61035#61035).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I don't think my question is an duplicate ... Because I asked a word for someone who insults themselves for flattery. A person mentioned a word "fishing for complimemts" that I can use. The link you provided is useful but this is for someone who wants sympathy ... Not flattery .

Comment: The principle is that 'fishing for compliments' has been given before in very similar threads, and ELU's aim is to present a comprehensive repository of sound English advice, not to give an answer to every slight variation on a query. It would become hopelessly bloated, and people would spend much time trying to find the suggestion 'fishing for compliments' say. Note that a moderator has now closed the question. _But you have the answer you requested!_

Answer (score 1):

The idiom for what she is doing is [fishing for compliments](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fish%20for%20compliments)

> to try to get people to say nice things about one

So compliment fisher would be an intelligible phrasing.

Comment: Apparently, this is considered not precise enough by at least one moderator; the exact same answer was given at a ... parallel ... thread.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternate usage of martyr that could apply.

"a person who feigns suffering to gain sympathy, help, etc"
vb (tr)

(usage is facetious or derogatory)

Comment: Pretty good, if youhave a link to the source dictionary for that meaning, it would improve your answer to [edit] and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Compassion extortionist, praise burglar.

This is what called passive-aggressive behavior, but it could be unintentional.

Comment: There are 3 hits in a Google search for 'compassion extortionist', two are false positives and one is this post. ELU deals with established usages.

Comment: "ELU deals with established usages" Sorry, I don't knew it.